# iOS 8 unwind segue leads to orientation error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have a View contoller A(VCA) that segues to View Controller B(VCB) modally. VCB has a button that unwinds back to VCA. The problem I am facing is that If I segue from VCA(portrait mode) to VCB and then change the orientation of VCB to landscape and then tap button to unwind, The VCA appears in portrait mode with half of the right screen all black. [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom animated view controller transition, try setting the frame of the view you are transitioning to:

```
extension CustomTransition: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func animateTransition(context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard
            let containerView = context.containerView(),
            let fromView = context.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey),
            let toView = context.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)
        else {
            return context.completeTransition(!context.transitionWasCancelled())
        }

        // This is the important line
        toView.frame = fromView.frame

        // Do your custom animations
    }
}
```